# Is there a method of fixing DtypeWarning for mixed column types in a script?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, powerbi

I'm using Python in a Power BI report on some relatively basic data. 15 columns imported into power BI from a txt flat file.

I wrote the following python code to create a dataframe from my data and pivot it:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame(dataset)
 df.pivot(index='Org Code', columns='Process Step', values='Status Change Date')
```

I get the following error, however:

```
DataSource.Error: ADO.NET: Python script error.
sys:1: DtypeWarning: Columns (2,7,13,14,15) have mixed types.Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

I have tried to set the datatypes in Power BI to what they should obviously be. Text columns to type text, date columns to date type, and so on. It doesn't fix the error. I also tried to pass in dtype:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dataset, dtype={'Category':'str'})
df.pivot(index='Org Code', columns='Process Step', values='Status Change Date')
```

Using dtype in the dataframe, however, didn't even remove column 2 from the error, which shows it doesn't work.

Comment: That's just a warning, not really an error, so the code should still work to read in the data. In your second attempt you only specify the dtype for a single column but the warning is telling you there are 5 problematic columns.

Comment: Also imagine you have a column that is 99.9999% int but has a few bad values like 'foo'. Pandas by default processes the data in chunks, so it's possible that for some chunks it sees all ints for that column, but in another chunk a single 'foo' exists so it must choose `'Object'`. You can use `low_memory=False` at the expense of memory, but since you read everything at once there cannot be mixed Datatypes as it's inferring only once